# Deleting a entity with a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

School Model

```
public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { set; get; }
}
```

User model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
    public int? SchoolId { get; set; } 
}
```

Repository:

```
 public virtual void Delete(T entityToDelete)
 {
     if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
     {
          dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
     }
     dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
 }
```

And Controller

```
 public ActionResult _Delete(int? id)
 {
     if(id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }

     School school = RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Find(id);
     if(school == null)
     {
          return HttpNotFound();
     }
     return PartialView(school);
   }

   [HttpPost, ActionName("SchoolDelete")]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
   {
       School school = RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Find(id);
       RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Delete(school);
       RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But when I try to delete School which have users connected to it I get an ex:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

So I tried to set null in every user school:

```
School school = RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Find(id);
foreach (var item in school.Users)
{
     var user = RepositoryFactory.Create<IUserRepository>().Find(item.Id);
     user.School = null;
     RepositoryFactory.Create<IUserRepository>().Update(user);
     RepositoryFactory.Create<IUserRepository>().SaveChanges();
}
RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Delete(school);
RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().SaveChanges();
```

But as a result of this i get:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.".

It works perfect when I dont have students in ICollection.

Comment: `See the inner exception for details.` what does the inner exception say?

Comment: Try to iterate with for loop backwards and remove from UserRepository.

Comment: i can`t use for loop with this ICollection, i get that error : "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Project.Models.User>"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I think it should work.

```
var school = RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Find(id);
var userRepository = RepositoryFactory.Create<IUserRepository>();

for (var i = school.Users.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     userRepository.Delete(school.Users[i]);
}
RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().Delete(school);
RepositoryFactory.Create<ISchoolRepository>().SaveChanges();
```

Comment: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Project.Models.User>'" So that doesnt helps.